# Select All that do not already exist in destination

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a simple set of arrays, kind of like this .. structure shortened for brevity and such. Basically it is a list of identities with an additional field (a sort of dictionary).

```
[
 { 
   "Id" : 1, 
   "Requirement" : { 
     "Value" : "2", "Name" : "Orders" 
    }
 },
 { 
   "Id" : 2, 
   "Requirement" : { 
     "Value" : "4", "Name" : "Orders" 
    }
 },
 { 
   "Id" : 3, 
   "Requirement" : { 
     "Value" : "6", "Name" : "Orders" 
    }
 },
 { 
   "Id" : 4, 
   "Requirement" : { 
     "Value" : "8", "Name" : "Orders" 
    }
 },
]
```

I need to be constantly checking another value against this array, and pulling in the items that are satisfied (for instance, the 'user' has an arbitrary value of `Orders` that is an integer. Each time `Orders` updates, I want to get all items out of the array where `Orders` is greater than or equal to the Requirement value, but without pulling in values they already have)

So then, this would work as follows ...
`User` has 1 `Order`. (Nothing Happens)
`User` has 2 `Order`. (Id 1 is pulled when the user's update operation runs)
`User` then achieves 4 `Order`. (Id 2 is pulled in, but Id 1 already exists, so it is skipped)

Is there a simplistic way to achieve this with a LINQ query? I don't have the luxury of storing the 'last checked' value. The data structure is not one I can modify at this point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Orders.Where(o => o.Requirement.Value > requirment).Except(processedOrders);
```

First select the `Orders` that meet the requirement, then using the `Except` remove the orders that have already been processed.

Comment: Thanks. This worked well. I discovered a new problem soon after, but this answered my specific question. The continued question is over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8659342/linq-select-all-that-match-a-single-field-merge-on-original

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Any` method to check for values not in another array:

```
myArray.Where(o => !otherArray.Any(inner => inner.id == o.id));
```