# LINQ : select all that match a single field, merge on original

Tags: c#, linq

Persuant to another question, my problem has extended a bit further. I have the following object shape ... ( I am using RavenDB, which is why I have 'strings' for identity)

This is not as complicated as I make it sound, but it is hard to communicate in brevity, so bear with me. If this makes no sense I will try to revise it.

### TLDR

`Collection A` has items I want to get, without getting the items in `Collection B` that have a matching ID. The two collections do not contain the same data type.

### Further Details

```
class Entity { 
  string Id { get; set; }
}
interface IName {
  string Name { get; set; }
}

class Reference<T> where T : Entity, IName {
  public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public static implicit operator Reference<T>(T doc) {
            return new Reference<T> {
                Id = doc.Id,
                Name = doc.Name
            };
        }
}
```

So then, if I have an object that has ..

`List<Reference<Product>>` I can assign products directly, and it will only store the Id/Name. This is my goal. However when it comes to list comparison this gets tricky.

So then, assume I have an array like this ..

```
[
 { 
   "Id" : 1, 
   "Requirement" : { 
     "Value" : "2", "Name" : "Orders" 
    }
 },
 { 
   "Id" : 2, 
   "Requirement" : { 
     "Value" : "4", "Name" : "Orders" 
    }
 },
 { 
   "Id" : 3, 
   "Requirement" : { 
     "Value" : "6", "Name" : "Orders" 
    }
 },
 { 
   "Id" : 4, 
   "Requirement" : { 
     "Value" : "8", "Name" : "Orders" 
    }
 },
]
```

And this is `Goals`. Then assume an array, `List<Reference<Goal>>`. This is nothing but a list of `Id` and `Name` of goals attained. (This is just a trivialized example for the sake of figuring this out. I know it is not entirely a practical shape)

So then, as stated in my other question (visible here : [Select All that do not already exist in destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657760/select-all-that-do-not-already-exist-in-destination)) I wanted to get the "Goals" that were met without getting duplicates each time it was run. This was solved with a simple query..

`Orders.Where(o => o.Requirement.Value > requirment).Except(processedOrders);`

That works if the target array and the source array are the same, but my 'target' is a `List<Reference<Order>>` and my source is a `List<Goal>`. The array works up to a point ...

Assuming that `User` has an object `Notebook` with two arrays. `List<Reference<Goal>>` is *GoalsReached* and `List<OrdersPlaced>`. where `OrdersPlaced` looks something like this ..

```
class OrdersPlaced {
  string ProductId { get; set; }
  int Quantity { get; set; }
}

var filtered = goals.Where(n => n.Requirements.Any(r => r.Name == order.Name))
                            .Where(m => m.Requirements.Any(p => p.Total <= order.Total))
                            .Select(n => n.Id)
                            .Except(user.Notebook.GoalsReached);
```

This is where the problem begins. GoalsReached is just a denormalized list of references, and cannot be back-converted to the original object without a lot of re-assembly. Is there any way to make this comparison smoother?

Comment: I'm sorry, is there some way that you can rephrase your question?  Here's what I understand so far:  You have 2 collections, A, and B.  The items in the collection are of a different data type, but they have an ID value that links them.  You want to get all of the items in A that do not already have a corresponding item in B.  Now, are you also saying that you have a 3rd collection (goals), with a 3rd datatype that you want to match?

Comment: You are right up until the last point. The final collection will contain the same type of data as B (the collection that has values I don't want to pull duplicates of). But yes, that is the general goal.

Comment: I added a smaller summary at the top. Like I said, it is hard to express in a succinct manner and still be clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using except, which requires having data of the same type to compare. You should do this as follows

```
var filtered = goals.Where(n => n.Requirements
                                 .Any(r => r.Name == order.Name))
                                 .Where(m => m.Requirements.Any(p => p.Total <= order.Total) 
                                             && !user.Notebook.GoalsReaches.Any(g => g.ID == n.Id))
                                 .Select(n => n.Id);
```